# Unable to encode byte array to UTF8 then decode it back to bytes

Tags: c#, utf-8

I'm trying to convert a byte array to a string, then at a later time convert those strings back to a byte array, but I'm getting some inconsistent results.

```
var salt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedPassword.Salt);
var key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedPassword.Key);
...
var saltBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
var keyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
```

In this case, the original salt and key are both byte[20], but the new ones are not equal (salt being a byte[36], key a byte [41], both with totally different values).

Comment: When I use what you have above my saltBytes == Salt and my keyBytes == Key.  What happens in your ... code?  What are your original values?

Comment: What are the contents of `encryptedPassword.Salt` and `encryptedPassword.Key`? Arbitrary bytes? That does not work; UTF8 [has rules](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629#page-5). You cannot expect arbitrary bytes to follow the UTF8 rules.

Comment: The contents are a salt and key generated from a Rfc2898DeriveBytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what @DourHighArch said. You can go string->binary->string, but you can't expect to be able to go binary->string->binary using text encoding.

For what you are doing, you probably want to use something like base64 encoding. So you could write it like this:

```
var salt = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedPassword.Salt);
var key = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedPassword.Key);
...
var saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination!  Using base64 encoding is working and what I was intending to do.